# how to i solve An error occurred: DOCKER_COMMAND_ERROR

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-aks

Im trying to login to an azure registry container on Azure Kubernetes Service, I get the error message below when i type the below azure CLI login command

```
az acr login --name myacrname

You may want to use 'az acr login -n myacrname --expose-token' to get an access token, which does not require Docker to be installed.
```

2022-09-01 12:26:43.255314 An error occurred: DOCKER_COMMAND_ERROR
error during connect: This error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running.: Get "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/containers/json": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Are you running the command directly on one of the nodes?

Comment: im running  from command line with azure cli installed on a window2 10 PC

Comment: Have you installed Docker Desktop on that PC?

Answer (score 1):

Error was caused by the Docker Desktop Service not running due to WSL (Windows Sub-system for Linux) Update wsl_update_x64.msi.
After installing, the error did not occur again when using the az acr login --name myacrname.

Answer (score 0):

You need to substitute the **Azure Service Principal ID** in the below command instead of 'XXXX' and use the appropriate Client secret instead of 'YYYY' to login to ACR,

```
az acr login -n <YOUR_ACR_URL> --username XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX --password YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
```